# Delphi TComPort WriteAsync

Tags: delphi, tcomport

I am trying to send a string through TComPort component asynchronously,
but everything is sent synchronously.
The issue is that the app will be blocked and wait until the transmission is over.

My code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  sss: string;
  i: Integer;
  t: cardinal;
begin
  sss:='';
  for i := 0 to 100 do
  begin
    sss:= sss + '1';
  end;

  memo1.Lines.Add('Str len - ' + IntToStr(Length(sss)));

  if self.MyPort1.Connected then
  begin
    InitAsync(Operation1);
    try
      self.MyPort1.WriteStrAsync(sss,Operation1);
      t:= GetTickCount;
      self.MyPort1.WaitForAsync(Operation1);
      t:= GetTickCount - t;
    finally
      DoneAsync(Operation1);
    end;    
    memo1.Lines.Add('Т - ' + IntToStr(t));
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing is asynchronous. But your call of `WaitForAsync` immediately after writing kills all the sense of asynchronous operation.

If you need to be sure in completion of writing, make `WaitForAsync` **before** the next writing operation (or before another action that requires writing completion).

In general - it is worth to wait for completion of overlapped operation in additional thread or use completion callback routine for notification